# Swagger: associate Integer to enum

Tags: java, enums, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to include swagger in my project but I cannot change the code or variable names.

I have a service which return a list of:

```
public class DetailResponse {

    private Integer code;
    private String description;
}
```

The code variable comes from a enum os possible errors:

```
public class ProgramException extends RuntimeException  {
    public enum TYPE {
        MAX_NUM_ITEMS(-1000),
        BAD_REQUEST(400),
        ANZAHLPACKSTUECKETABLE(-20000),
        PACKNUMBER(-20001),
```

is it possible to associate "code" and the TYPE enum so I can show a list of options in the swagger documentation generated?

Similar to:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ApiModel`

```
@ApiModel
public enum Day {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday;
}
```